# Resharper move single class - currently selects all in file since update

Tags: resharper

Since a recent update of Resharper, when I put my caret on a class name and choose [Resharper Move](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_File.html), it automatically selects all of the classes in that file.  It used to only select the class I had my caret on in the dialog window.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>O</kbd> to instigate the move, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> has the same effect with the caret on the class.

Is it possible to configure it back to only selecting the single class that I had my caret on?

I am running Resharper 2016.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is a reported bug on the Resharper bug tracker.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462423

A fix should be out for this in a future update.